# Symfony2 login route keeps redirecting to https

Tags: symfony, authentication, https, routes

I have experimented with FOS user and facebook bundle and when I wanted to return back to my implemented login process something went wrong. Everything should be back to normal, but when I go to /login page, it keeps redirecting to https (which I have not turned it on in apache, so it fails)..

I haven't found anything in logs. I thought it should be somewhere outside of my bundle, because the request never reached the `SecurityController`. I also deleted all the FOS-related files. Any help yould be appreciated.

from `security.yml`

```
    firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    secured_area:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: ~
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        #remember_me:
        #    key: "%secret%"
        #    lifetime: 31536000
        #    path: /
        #    domain: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

from `routing.yml`

```
login:
    pattern:   /login
    defaults:  { _controller: TnDWWebBundle:Security:login }

login_check:
    pattern:   /login_check
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `requires_channel` parameter to force HTTP over HTTPS in your `security.yml`:

```
access_control:
    - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY, requires_channel: http }
```

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#securing-by-channel

Answer (score 0):

You should try [JmikolaInsecureRoutesBundle](https://github.com/jmikola/JmikolaInsecureRoutesBundle)